# opengl texture glTexCoord2f is not working properly

Tags: opengl, glut

I am new to opengl. I am so confused with glTexCoord2f. I don't know how to provide the coordinates. I just know coordinate should be (0,0) (0,1) (1,0) and (1,1).When I provide a texture on a plane ( here plane is for a door) , it does not display the bmp image properly..I have tried by changing coordinates randomly but the shape of the image changes but it is not displaying the image straight vertical. What will be the coordinates to show the image as it is ( a straight vertical door) .

```
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, main_door);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
        glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        glVertex3f(-400,0,0);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        glVertex3f(400,0,0);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        glVertex3f(400,0,1000);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        glVertex3f(-400,0,1000);
    }glEnd();
}
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

My full code

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>
      #include<windows.h> 
     #include<GL/glut.h>

     double cameraAngle;
     double move_X, move_Y, move_Z;
    int canDrawGrid, canDrawAxis,canDrawBase;

     double cameraRadius, cameraHeight, cameraAngleDelta;
     int num_texture  = -1;
     GLuint grassimg,md1img,brick_d123,dome_top,dome_t_d,dome_t_d_2,floorimg,sideimg,main_door;


     int LoadBitmapImage(char *filename)
     {
    int i, j=0;
    FILE *l_file;
    unsigned char *l_texture;

    BITMAPFILEHEADER fileheader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER infoheader;
    RGBTRIPLE rgb;

    num_texture++;

    if( (l_file = fopen(filename, "rb"))==NULL) return (-1);

    fread(&fileheader, sizeof(fileheader), 1, l_file);

    fseek(l_file, sizeof(fileheader), SEEK_SET);
    fread(&infoheader, sizeof(infoheader), 1, l_file);

    l_texture = (byte *) malloc(infoheader.biWidth * infoheader.biHeight * 4);
    memset(l_texture, 0, infoheader.biWidth * infoheader.biHeight * 4);
    for (i=0; i < infoheader.biWidth*infoheader.biHeight; i++)
        {
                fread(&rgb, sizeof(rgb), 1, l_file);

                l_texture[j+0] = rgb.rgbtRed;
                l_texture[j+1] = rgb.rgbtGreen;
                l_texture[j+2] = rgb.rgbtBlue;
                l_texture[j+3] = 255;
                j += 4;
        }
    fclose(l_file);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, num_texture);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

// glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, infoheader.biWidth, infoheader.biHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, l_texture);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, infoheader.biWidth, infoheader.biHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, l_texture);

    free(l_texture);

    return (num_texture);

}

void loadImage()
{
    grassimg = LoadBitmapImage("image/brick.bmp");
    brick_d123 = LoadBitmapImage("image/brick_d123.bmp");
    md1img = LoadBitmapImage("image/m_d_1.bmp");
        dome_top = LoadBitmapImage("image/dome_top.bmp");
        dome_t_d = LoadBitmapImage("image/dome_t_d.bmp");
        dome_t_d_2 = LoadBitmapImage("image/dome_t_d_2.bmp");
        floorimg = LoadBitmapImage("image/floor.bmp");
        sideimg = LoadBitmapImage("image/side_1.bmp");
        main_door = LoadBitmapImage("image/main_door.bmp");
    printf("Load successful");
}


void choto_gombuj(double tx,double ty, double tz,double deg,double axisX,double axisY,double axisZ,double sx,double sy, double sz){
    glPushMatrix();{
        glTranslatef(tx,ty,tz);
        glRotatef(deg,axisX,axisY,axisZ);
        glScalef(sx,sx,sz);
        //CG_base_cyclindeer
        GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brick_d123);
        gluCylinder(obj,190,190,60,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


        //CG_base_base_dakna
        glColor3f(0,0,0);

        glPushMatrix();{
                glTranslatef(0,0,59);
                glutSolidCone(189,1,20,20);
        }glPopMatrix();
        //CG_Cylinder_pillar_8
        glPushMatrix();{
        glTranslatef(120,120,59);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassimg);
            gluCylinder(obj,12,12,220,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();


        glPushMatrix();{
        glTranslatef(170,0,59);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassimg);
            gluCylinder(obj,12,12,220,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();



            glPushMatrix();{
        glTranslatef(120,-120,59);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassimg);
            gluCylinder(obj,12,12,220,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(0,-170,59);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassimg);
            gluCylinder(obj,12,12,220,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(-120,-120,59);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassimg);
            gluCylinder(obj,12,12,220,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(-170,0,59);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassimg);
            gluCylinder(obj,12,12,220,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(-120,120,59);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassimg);
            gluCylinder(obj,12,12,220,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(0,170,59);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassimg);
            gluCylinder(obj,12,12,220,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();



        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(0,0,220+59);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, md1img);
            gluCylinder(obj,220,0,60,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();




        // main_dome
        glPushMatrix();{
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glTranslatef(0,0,440);

        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(0,0,150);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dome_t_d);
            GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
            gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
                gluCylinder(obj,160,0,130,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        }glPopMatrix();

        double equ[4];
        equ[0]=0;
        equ[1]=0;
        equ[2]=1;
        equ[3]=150;

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dome_top);
            GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
            gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
            glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE0,equ);
            glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);{
                gluSphere(obj,220,20,20);
            }glDisable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);



    }glPopMatrix();


        //dome_top_balls
        glPushMatrix();{
                glTranslatef(0,0,740);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dome_t_d_2);
            GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
            gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
                gluSphere(obj,40,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();


        glPushMatrix();{
                glTranslatef(0,0,810);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dome_t_d_2);
            GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
            gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
                gluSphere(obj,35,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();



        glPushMatrix();{
                glTranslatef(0,0,865);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dome_t_d_2);
            GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
            gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
                gluSphere(obj,30,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();{
                glTranslatef(0,0,910);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dome_t_d_2);
            GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
            gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
                gluSphere(obj,25,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();




}glPopMatrix();
}

void minar(double tx,double ty, double tz,double deg,double axisX,double axisY,double axisZ){
    glPushMatrix();{
        glTranslatef(tx,ty,tz);
        glRotatef(deg,axisX,axisY,axisZ);
    //Minar_base
    GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
        glColor3f(0,0,0);
        glPushMatrix();{
            gluCylinder(obj,150,140,240,20,20);
        }glPopMatrix();
    //Minar_base_base_dakna
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(0,0,240);
            glutSolidCone(142,1,20,20);
    }glPopMatrix();
    //Minar_main_pillar

    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassimg);
        GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
        gluCylinder(obj,105,70,1500,20,20);
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    //Minar_design_3_plate_1
    glPushMatrix();{
        glTranslatef(0,0,600);
        glRotatef(180,0,1,0);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, md1img);
        GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
        gluCylinder(obj,135,0,100,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brick_d123);
        GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
        gluCylinder(obj,135,0,1,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    }glPopMatrix();
    ////Minar_design_3_plate_2
    glPushMatrix();{
        glTranslatef(0,0,1050);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glRotatef(180,0,1,0);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, md1img);
        GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
        gluCylinder(obj,120,0,100,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brick_d123);
        GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
        gluCylinder(obj,120,0,1,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    }glPopMatrix();
    ////Minar__design_3_plate_3
    glPushMatrix();{
        glTranslatef(0,0,1500);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glRotatef(180,0,1,0);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, md1img);
        GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
        gluCylinder(obj,105,0,100,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brick_d123);
        GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricTexture(obj,GL_TRUE);
        gluCylinder(obj,105,0,1,20,20);
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    }glPopMatrix();
    choto_gombuj(0,0,1500,0,0,0,0,0.4,0.4,0.4);
}glPopMatrix();
}


void display(){
    //codes for Models, Camera

    //clear the display
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);  //color black
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);     //clear buffers to preset values

    /***************************
    / set-up camera (view) here
    ****************************/ 
    //load the correct matrix -- MODEL-VIEW matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     //specify which matrix is the current matrix

    //initialize the matrix
    glLoadIdentity();               //replace the current matrix with the identity matrix [Diagonals have 1, others have 0]

    //now give three info
    //1. where is the camera (viewer)?
    //2. where is the camera looking?
    //3. Which direction is the camera's UP direction?

    //gluLookAt(0,-150,20,  0,0,0,  0,0,1);
    gluLookAt(cameraRadius*sin(cameraAngle), -cameraRadius*cos(cameraAngle), cameraHeight,      0,0,0,      0,0,1);

    //again select MODEL-VIEW
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);


    /**************************************************
    / Grid and axes Lines(You can remove them if u want)
    ***************************************************/
    // draw the three major AXES

    if(canDrawAxis==1){
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            //X axis
            glColor3f(0, 1, 0); //100% Green
            glVertex3f(-4000, 0, 0);
            glVertex3f( 4000, 0, 0);

            //Y axis
            glColor3f(0, 0, 1); //100% Blue
            glVertex3f(0, -4000, 0);    // intentionally extended to -150 to 150, no big deal
            glVertex3f(0,  4000, 0);

            //Z axis
            glColor3f(1, 1, 1); //100% White
            glVertex3f( 0, 0, -4000);
            glVertex3f(0, 0, 4000);
        glEnd();
    }

    if(canDrawGrid == 1){
    //some gridlines along the field
        int i;

        glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);   //grey
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            for(i=-160;i<=160;i++){

                if(i==0)
                    continue;   //SKIP the MAIN axes

                //lines parallel to Y-axis
                glVertex3f(i*20, -3600, 0);
                glVertex3f(i*20,  3600, 0);

                //lines parallel to X-axis
                glVertex3f(-3600, i*20, 0);
                glVertex3f( 3600, i*20, 0);
            }
        glEnd();

    }



    /****************************
    / Add your objects from here
    ****************************/

    if(canDrawBase == 1){

        //base_floor
        glColor3f(0,1,0);  
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
            glVertex3f(-3600,3600,0);
            glVertex3f(3600,3600,0);
            glVertex3f(3600,-3600,0);
            glVertex3f(-3600,-3600,0);
        }glEnd();
    }
    //taj_base
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    //right_base_wall
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sideimg);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
            glColor3f(1,1,1);
            glTexCoord2f(0,1);
            glVertex3f(2000,2000,0);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex3f(2000,-2000,0);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex3f(2000,-2000,240);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex3f(2000,2000,240);
        }glEnd();
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    //left_base_wall
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sideimg);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
            glColor3f(1,1,1);
            glTexCoord2f(0,1);
            glVertex3f(-2000,2000,0);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex3f(-2000,-2000,0);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex3f(-2000,-2000,240);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex3f(-2000,2000,240);
        }glEnd();
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    //back_base_wall
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sideimg);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
            glColor3f(1,1,1);
            glTexCoord2f(0,1);
            glVertex3f(-2000,2000,0);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex3f(2000,2000,0);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex3f(2000,2000,240);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex3f(-2000,2000,240);
        }glEnd();
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    glColor3f(1,1,1);
        //font__base_wall
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sideimg);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
            glColor3f(1,1,1);
            glTexCoord2f(0,1);
            glVertex3f(-2000,-2000,0);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex3f(2000,-2000,0);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex3f(2000,-2000,240);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex3f(-2000,-2000,240);
        }glEnd();
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);



    glColor3f(1,1,1);
        //font_top_wall
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, floorimg);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
            glColor3f(1,1,1);
            glTexCoord2f(0,1);
            glVertex3f(-2000,2000,240);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex3f(2000,2000,240);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex3f(2000,-2000,240);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex3f(-2000,-2000,240);
        }glEnd();
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);










    /*//taj_base_shiri_cube
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(0,-2050,120);
            //glRotatef(-16,1,0,0);
            glScalef(500,100,240);
            glutSolidCube(1);
        }glPopMatrix();

    */


    minar(-1950,-1950,0,0,0,0,0);
    minar(1950,-1950,0,0,0,0,0);
    minar(1950,1950,0,0,0,0,0);
    minar(-1950,1950,0,0,0,0,0);


    //taj_main_building
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(0,-1200,240);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, main_door);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex3f(-400,0,0);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex3f(400,0,0);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex3f(400,0,1000);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex3f(-400,0,1000);
        }glEnd();
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }glPopMatrix();



    //ADD this line in the end --- if you use double buffer (i.e. GL_DOUBLE)
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void animate(){
    //codes for any changes in Models, Camera

    //cameraAngle += cameraAngleDelta;  // camera will rotate at 0.002 radians per frame.

    //codes for any changes in Models

    //MISSING SOMETHING? -- YES: add the following
    glutPostRedisplay();    //this will call the display AGAIN

}

void init(){
    //codes for initialization
    loadImage();
    cameraAngle = 0;    //angle in radian
    move_X = 0;
    move_Y = 0;
    move_Z = 0;
    canDrawGrid = 1;
    canDrawAxis = 1;
    canDrawBase = 1;
    cameraAngleDelta = .001;

    cameraRadius = 4000;
    cameraHeight = 500;

    //clear the screen
    glClearColor(0,0,0, 0);

    /************************
    / set-up projection here
    ************************/
    //load the PROJECTION matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    //initialize the matrix
    glLoadIdentity();

    /*
        gluPerspective() — set up a perspective projection matrix

        fovy -         Specifies the field of view angle, in degrees, in the y direction.
        aspect ratio - Specifies the aspect ratio that determines the field of view in the x direction. The aspect ratio is the ratio of x (width) to y (height).
        zNear -        Specifies the distance from the viewer to the near clipping plane (always positive).
        zFar  -        Specifies the distance from the viewer to the far clipping plane (always positive).
    */

    gluPerspective(70,  1,  0.1,    10000.0);

}

void keyboardListener(unsigned char key, int x,int y){
    switch(key){

        case '1':
            move_X += 1;
            break;

        case '2':   
            move_X -= 1;
            break;

        case '3':   
            move_Y += 1;
            break;
        case '4':   
            move_Y -= 1;
            break;

        case '5':   
            move_Z += 1;
            break;
        case '6':   
            move_Z -= 1;
            break;
        case '8':   

            break;

        case 'g':
            canDrawGrid ^= 1;
            break;

        case 'h':
            canDrawAxis ^= 1;
            break;

        case 'p':
            break;

        case 'z':
            canDrawBase ^= 1;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

void specialKeyListener(int key, int x,int y){
    switch(key){
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:     //down arrow key
            cameraRadius += 40;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_UP:       // up arrow key
            if(cameraRadius > 40)
                cameraRadius -= 40;
            break;

        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            cameraAngle += 0.05;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            cameraAngle -= 0.05;
            break;

        case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:
            cameraHeight += 40;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:
            cameraHeight -= 40;
            break;

        case GLUT_KEY_INSERT:
            break;

        case GLUT_KEY_HOME:
        //  cameraAngleDelta = 0.001; 
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_END:
        //  cameraAngleDelta = 0;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

void mouseListener(int button, int state, int x, int y){    //x, y is the x-y of the screen (2D)
    switch(button){
        case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
            if(state == GLUT_DOWN){     // 2 times?? in ONE click? -- solution is checking DOWN or UP
                cameraAngleDelta = -cameraAngleDelta;   
            }
            break;

        case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
            if(cameraRadius > 40)
                cameraRadius -= 40;
            break;

        case GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON:
            //........
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    glutInit(&argc,argv);                           //initialize the GLUT library

    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);

    /*
        glutInitDisplayMode - inits display mode
        GLUT_DOUBLE - allows for display on the double buffer window
        GLUT_RGBA - shows color (Red, green, blue) and an alpha
        GLUT_DEPTH - allows for depth buffer
    */
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);   

    glutCreateWindow("Some Title");

    init();                     //codes for initialization

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    //enable Depth Testing

    glutDisplayFunc(display);   //display callback function
    glutIdleFunc(animate);      //what you want to do in the idle time (when no drawing is occuring)

    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardListener);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeyListener);

    glutMouseFunc(mouseListener);

    glutMainLoop();     //The main loop of OpenGL

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code shows the coordinate `1,0` repeated twice. This problem exists in addition to the more serious one I described in my answer. Between both of those things, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What are the dimensions of your bitmap?

There is a gotcha that catches a lot of people off guard when using RGB image formats, which is that pixel rows are expected to begin on 4-byte boundaries by default in GL.

From your description it is not your texture coordinates that are to blame at all.

The actual data that GL read in the first place was misinterpreted and it pulled each row of your texture from the wrong data location. If your bitmap's width is not a multiple of 4 then you will need to tell GL to use different rules when unpacking the pixel data transferred to it.

#### Generally, incompatible texture widths can be corrected as follows:

```
glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

---

*It is **very** important to note here that DIB (`.bmp`) images already satisfy the 4-byte row alignment rules that OpenGL expects. If you correctly read a `.bmp` image, this problem never exists in the first place.*

You have not compensated for the padding at the end of each row that will already be present in a `.bmp` file whose width is not a multiple of 4. That needs to be done first and will make the GL command above unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you...the problem was with the image. Image should be multiple of 4.